# Pyodbc returning query results intermittently

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am completely stumped as I the code can connect to the database and returns the required results.  However, running this multiple times does not give the same results.  I either get all the records expected back or there are no records that come back. I do not make any changes which is why I do not understand what is making the issue intermittent.

Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
pyodbc.pooling = False

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER="SERVER\\LOCATION",PORTNUM;DATABASE=DBNAME;UID=USERNAME;
PWD=PASSWORD;chunksize =100')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

sql="SELECT ida,idb,name  from schema.dbo.table  where ida=? and idb=? and date_x between '1-jan-12' and '31-dec-12' order by date_x"

df1 = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn,params={'ida','idb'})

sql="SELECT ida,idb,name  from schema.dbo.table  where ida=? and idb=? and date_x between '1-jan-12' and '31-dec-12' order by date_x"

df2 = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn,params={'idc','idd'})
```